# Can password_verify() be used to identify password after database breach?

Tags: hash, php

I am a newbie to PHP and password hashing. I am following the instructions provided @ [Safe Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) to hash my user password before storing.

My questions are:

1. PHP recommends `password_hash()` method as a preferred secure way to hash. In case of a database breach won’t the hacker use `password_verify()` and identify the passwords rather than using a rainbow look up table?
2. If so, what should be my approach to close this security gap?

Comment: Sure they can, it's called a brute force attack, and it's way less efficient than rainbow tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`password_verify()` takes two arguments: a string of which you want to check if it's the correct password, and the value you calculated earlier with `password_hash()`, which you presumably stored somewhere in a database or so.

A typical application could be:

```
<?php
$hash = password_hash('my-secret', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// normally you would save the hash somewhere, but we'll just continue in this example

$check_a = 'other-secret';
$check_b = 'my-secret';
if (password_verify($check_a, $hash))
   echo 'Check A was the original password: ' . $check_a;
if (password_verify($check_b, $hash))
   echo 'Check B was the original password: ' . $check_b;
```

The output will be:

```
Check B was the original password: my-secret
```

If you want to get the original password from a hash calculated by `password_hash()`, you'll need to try all possibilities - that's what this example shows. Because of the architecture of `password_hash()`, finding a password like this will take a long time, so it's not worth it.

Note also, from the [`password_hash()` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

> **`PASSWORD_DEFAULT`** - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

The algorithm is designed to change over time, so that it stays secure, and finding a password by brute force won't become possible with faster computers (presuming, the PHP installation on your server is up to date)

**In any case, a *hash* is one-way: you can't turn it around. You can only verify a given password by computing the hash of *that* one, and checking if it's the same.**

Answer (score 0):

`password_verify()` will only confirm if a given password matches the given hash.  It still requires an input, and rainbow tables are a way to generate possible passwords for input.  However, if you're generating a recommended size salt value it will help protect against rainbow table attacks.

You can find more on correctly securing passwords using hashes and salts by reading [How to Securely Hash Passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I completely forgot the part where the password is required as the input.

Comment: Although it is not the answer to your question, you should read this: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since the hash functions are really hard to invert you can't simply deduce a solution by providing the hash. There is a negligible probability that an attacker can develop a strategy to find a password that's digest matches with the one you store at the database. Don't know whats PHP's default hash method but all the modern hashing algorithms are collision resistant, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to actually get the real password is use a brute force attack on the hashed password, as the default php password hash algorithm is bcrypt it would take a hell of a lot of time.